# DateTimePicker - Disable the times that have already passed in the day (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I currently integrating the XDSoft DateTimePicker (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) JQuery into my website and wish to disable the times that have passed. Currently if i select today then i can still select a time which has already passed.

I tried using minTime:0 but this also disables times on sunsequent days. I want to be able to select a start and end time (e.g. 9am-5:30pm) which i can do with mintime and max time but i cant disable the times which have already passed today.

Below is my script:

```
<script>
    jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        step: 60,
        minTime: '09:00',
        maxTime: '17:30',
        todayButton: true,
        format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
        inline: true,
        lang: 'en'

    });</script>
```

Comment: You could apply the restriction on the `onShow()` event handler that the plugin provides.

Comment: is that easy to implement?

Comment: It depends. You'll need some scripting for sure.

Comment: Try: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#mindate

Comment: not sure you can with this plugin

Answer (score 0):

Yes setting *minTime* to 0 will disables times on subsequent days also. You need to change the *minTime* option depending upon the date. If it is today, *minTime* will remain the same, else *minTime* will be set to *false*.

```
$("#element").datetimepicker({ format: 'Y-m-d H:i', minDate: 0, minTime: 0, onSelectDate: function(ct) {
        var dtob = new Date(),
            current_date = dtob.getDate(),
            current_month = dtob.getMonth() + 1,
            current_year = dtob.getFullYear();

        // today's date 
        var full_date = current_year + '-' +
                        ( current_month < 10 ? '0' + current_month : current_month ) + '-' + 
                        ( current_date < 10 ? '0' + current_date : current_date );

        // compare today's date to the date chosen
        if(ct.dateFormat('Y-m-d') == full_date)
            this.setOptions({ minTime: 0 });
        else 
            this.setOptions({ minTime: false });    
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is stucked,try this out

```
$( function() {
var checkPastTime = function(inputDateTime) {
  if (typeof(inputDateTime) != "undefined" && inputDateTime !== null) {
      var current = new Date();
      if (inputDateTime.getFullYear() < current.getFullYear()) {
          $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker('reset');
          alert("Sorry! Past date time not allow.");
      } else if ((inputDateTime.getFullYear() == current.getFullYear()) && (inputDateTime.getMonth() < current.getMonth())) {
          $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker('reset');
          alert("Sorry! Past date time not allow.");
      }
      if (inputDateTime.getDate() == current.getDate()) {
          if (inputDateTime.getHours() < current.getHours()) {
              $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker('reset');
          }
          this.setOptions({
              minTime: current.getHours() + ':00' //here pass current time hour
          });
      } else {
          this.setOptions({
              minTime: false
          });
      }
  }
};
var currentYear = new Date();
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format:'Y-m-d H:i',
    minDate : 0,
    yearStart : currentYear.getFullYear(), // Start value for current Year selector
    onChangeDateTime:checkPastTime,
    onShow:checkPastTime
});
```

});

credit:

> https://www.thecodedeveloper.com/disable-past-date-time/